# A question in Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2},&x\ne 0\\\\0,&x=0\end{cases}$$

I have shown that

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}x=0$$

$$\begin{align}
f''(0)&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}-0}{x-0}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
f'''(0)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f''(x)-f''(0)}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}\frac{4-6x^2}{x^6}}{x}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(4-6x^2)}{x^7e^{1/x^2}}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

But now I am trying to show the more general case $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n\ge0$. So if I can prove that $x\ne 0, f^{(n)}(x)$ has the form $p_n(\frac{1}{x})e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ where $p_n$ is a polynomial then this should solve my question. But how do I go about proving that general case?

Answer (score 4):

Show a recursive formula for $g_n(x)=\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{f(x)}$ for $x\neq 0$.

This will yield that $g_n(x)$ is a rational function for all $n$.

Then show that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{x}= 0$$ using what you know about $g_n(x)$.

This ultimately involves showing:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^k}=0$$ 
for any $k$.

Comment: how do I choose that recursive formula?

Comment: Hint: You don't choose.

Comment: I am a little confused with your method

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to go about it in the way you outlined, you may note that if for any given $n$ 
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (e^{-1/x^2}) =
P_n(\frac1x)e^{-1/x^2}
$$
with $P_n(s)$ a polynomial
$$
P_n(s)= \sum_{k=0}^m a_k s^k
$$
then using the multiplication rule and the chain rule
$$
\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (e^{-1/x^2}) =-2\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^{-k-3}e^{-1/x^2}
-\frac1{x^2}\sum_{k=0}^m k a_k x^{-k}e^{-1/x^2} 
$$
and by combining terms, you get a different polynomial in $\frac1x$ times $e^{-1/x^2}$.

So you have proved this by induction (the basis, for $=1$, you had already proven above).

Comment: how do I combine those terms? and does this fully prove my question? thanks for your submission